# Looking for currency gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a rails gem to have a text_field that I can put a number and have a select where I can select a symbols of money ($, €...). If I change the select again that change the value of the text_field.

Anyone know a good gem for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Money Gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money). It has currency convertor built in, formatting, and lots of other great stuff to work with money.

Answer (score 1):

See [Font Awesome Icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) gem. It's contains some symbols of money and many other helpful symbols